# Copy substring of string array into new array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, sorting

I am looking to copy the substring of a string array into a new array without creating references. This is giving me a headache yet this should be fairly simple.

I tried `NewArray[n] = OldArray[n].substr(x,y).slice(0)` inside a loop and does not work. (I need to do a `NewArray.sort()` afterwards).

For the sake of example, say I got an `OldArray` with 2 elements:

```
['River', 'Lake']
```

I want the new array to be made of the first 2 characters (substring) of the old one such that:

```
['Ri', 'La']
```

Answer (score 1):

> copy the substring of a string array into a new array without creating references

Strings are primitive values in JavaScript, not Objects. There will be no reference when assigning the values of the old into the new array, especially when creating new strings with `substr`. The `slice(0)` you've used is superfluous when used with strings, and not necessary on arrays in your case, too.

Your code should work:

```
var oldArray = ["River", "Lake"];

var newArray = [];
for (var i=0; i<oldArray.length; i++)
   newArray[i] = oldArray[i].substr(0,2);

// newArray: ["Ri", "La"]
```

Comment: One day, in a distant future, we'll be using ECMAScript 5's [`Array.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) for this. :P

Comment: Thank you! I finally noticed that indeed the error was a bit lower in the code. I tested the sort and the problem is int the treatment of the output.

Comment: you could also just use `newArray.push(oldArray[i].substr(0,2));`

Comment: @MattiasBuelens: Yes, but I think `var newArray=oldArray.map(function(str){return str.substr(0,2);});` is a little overhead here. The loop will be much faster.

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me. Thanks @Bergi

```
const newArray = oldArray.map( str => str.substr(0,2) );
```